# stl_writer.Write not saving any file

Tags: python, pythonocc

I am trying to convert from stp to stl. The code is:

```
rom OCC.Core.STEPControl import STEPControl_Reader
from OCC.Core.StlAPI import StlAPI_Writer
import os
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


input_file  = 'stl_test.stp'   # input STEP (AP203/AP214 file)
output_file = 'stl_test.stl'   # output X3D file


step_reader = STEPControl_Reader()
step_reader.ReadFile( input_file )
step_reader.TransferRoot()
myshape = step_reader.Shape()
print("File readed")

# Export to STL
stl_writer = StlAPI_Writer()
stl_writer.SetASCIIMode(True)
stl_writer.Write(myshape, output_file)
print(stl_writer.Write(myshape, output_file))
print("Written")
```

THis is not saving anything in the working dir. And `print(stl_writer.Write(myshape, output_file))` is giving false output.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, even though your way is like it is told in the docs...

The following solution worked for me:

```
# Imports
from OCC.Core.STEPControl import STEPControl_Reader
from OCC.Core.StlAPI import StlAPI_Writer
from OCC.Core.BRepMesh import BRepMesh_IncrementalMesh


input_file  = 'stl_test.stp'   # input STEP (AP203/AP214 file)
output_file = 'stl_test.stl'   # output X3D file


### load stp file
step_reader = STEPControl_Reader()
stat = step_reader.ReadFile(input_file)
if stat == 1:
    step_reader.TransferRoot()
    body = step_reader.Shape()
else:
    print('...........Load failed')
    return 'Error'
print("File read")

### Convert and export body to STL File
mesh = BRepMesh_IncrementalMesh(body, 0.1)
writer = StlAPI_Writer()
writer.Write(mesh.Shape(), output_file)
print("Written")
```

Maybe it has something to do with the "AP203/AP214 file"?! I don't realy know.